# NGINX throws 404 and wont load static

Tags: django, linux, nginx

Hopefully, Y'all can help me with this one and hopefully I am in the right areas to post this. Just recently began learning Django and I am trying to get it deployed to Linux. I have been using gunicorn and nginx for this deployment and for the most part I have been successful. I am able to successfully deploy and interact with my app, navigate pages and interact with some of the post requests. The only thing I have been banging my head around trying to figure out what is going on with my static files.  All of my css and images do not display currently and I have tried searching everywhere for the resolution. I have tried using an alias in the nginx file and I have made sure that my static root and URL is fine, nothing i have tried has done the trick. the weird this is, when looking at the access logs from nginx it shows the Get request going to the correct file and path, but shows 404? I am at a loss here lol! What is really weird is that the static folder contains a few csv's that are processed and served by a view those work correctly so I am confident that the url and root in setting.py is correct. Some of the other things I have tried include setting STATIC_URL to '/' and '/Static_File_Storage' neither worked one gave me an error about media url and the other gave me a permission denied error. This is also for a network-only site and won't be accessed by anyone other than a few employees so I am not worried about having it pulling from home.

```
**NGINX FILE:**
server {
listen 80;
server_name redacted;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /Static_File_Storage/ {
    alias /home/beachhouse/PycharProjects/BH_Django_Project/BH_DJANGO/Static_File_Storage/;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}}

**setting.py**
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/Static_File_Storage/")
STATIC_URL = 'home/beachhouse/PycharmProjects/BH_Django_Project/BH_DJANGO/Static_File_Storage/'

**Actual Location of File:** /home/beachhouse/PycharmProjects/BH_Django_Project/BH_DJANGO/Static_File_Storage/css/style.css

**output on logs: "GET** /home/beachhouse/PycharmProjects/BH_Django_Project/BH_DJANGO/Static_File_Storage/home/beachhouse/PycharmProjects/BH_Django_Project/BH_DJANGO_Static_File_Storage/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1226

**Static Tags in HTML:** {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
<img class="login_img" src="{% static '/logo.png' %}" alt="logo">
View call for static: df = pandas.read_csv(static('Flash_Changes.csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `STATIC_URL` to `"/Static_File_Storage/"`.

Comment: Thank you!!!! It ended up being a typo in the NGINX file location alias but i couldn't see it on the error logs till i changed the STATIC_URL